# loading JSON file using JavaScript in JSP

Tags: javascript, json, jsp, extjs

I am a beginner for develop Spring application. I want to use Extjs in front end.
So I was include JavaScript(Extjs) into JSP page, and load JSON file in JavaScript.
Following is my snippet of codes.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bAU8.jpg)
Who solves this problem?
Help me please..

Comment: Remove the dot before the slash? `./` Try calling the file directly via url and check if it's accessible from this path.

Answer (score 0):

First step: read and understand the error message. Your static JSON file is fetched with `method:'POST'` and tells you

> METHOD NOT ALLOWED

Second step: try another `method`. Your best bet would be `method:'GET'`, but there are others (other valid methods can be found easily using google). Repeat step 2 until the error message goes away or changes. If the error message changes, go back to step 1.